# sql Left Join, max value

Tags: sql, group-by, max, left-join

### **Hi every one,**

I found similar subjects but can't get what I want.

I have got 3 tables:

MESSAGE(rows: MID, CONTENT, SENTDATE)

RECEIVED (rows: RID, MEMBRE, FK_RE_MESSAGE_ID (foreign key: message.ID))

GROUP(rows: GID, MICROID,FK_GR_MESSAGE_ID (foreign key: message.ID))

I would like to get last message of each group for a member ID
Based on googling, this is the last request I have tried:

---

```
SELECT * 
FROM MESSAGE as msg
LEFT JOIN RECEIVED AS rcd ON msg.MID=rcd.FK_RE_MESSAGE_ID 
LEFT JOIN GROUP AS grp ON msg.MID=grp.FK_GR_MESSAGE_ID
INNER JOIN (SELECT MID, MAX( SENTDATE) AS lastdate
FROM MESSAGE
GROUP BY MID) MESSAGE ON msg.MID=MESSAGE.MID
WHERE (rcd .MEMBRE)*
```

---

This is returning all message in any groups for the chosen membre.

Please could someone help me?

Comment: What DMBS do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to fix your last `join` condition:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MESSAGE as msg LEFT JOIN
     RECEIVED AS rcd
     ON msg.MID=rcd.FK_RE_MESSAGE_ID LEFT JOIN
     "GROUP" AS grp
     ON msg.MID=grp.FK_GR_MESSAGE_ID INNER JOIN
     (SELECT MID, MAX( SENTDATE) AS lastdate
      FROM MESSAGE
      GROUP BY MID
     ) MESSAGE
     ON msg.MID = MESSAGE.MID and msg.SENTDATE = MESSAGE.lastdate
WHERE (rcd .MEMBRE)*;
```

If you are filtering the data and have an index on `MESSAGE(MID, SENTDATE)`, then the following should perform better;

```
SELECT * 
FROM MESSAGE as msg LEFT JOIN
     RECEIVED AS rcd
     ON msg.MID = rcd.FK_RE_MESSAGE_ID LEFT JOIN
     "GROUP" AS grp
     ON msg.MID = grp.FK_GR_MESSAGE_ID
WHERE (rcd .MEMBRE)* and
      not exists (select 1
                  from message m2
                  where m2.mid = msg.mid and m2.sentdate > msg.sentdate
                 );
```